# SQL Server FTI: How to check table status?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

In the SQL Server Full-Text Indexing scheme i want to know if a table is in

- `start_chage_tracking` mode
- `update_index` mode
- `start_change_tracking` and `start_background_updateindex` modes

The problem is that i set my tables to "background update index", and then tell it to "start change tracking", but then some months later it doesn't seem to be tracking changes.

How i can i see the status of "background updateindex" and "change tracking" flags?

**example:**

```
sp_fulltext_table @tabname='DiaryEntry', @action='start_background_updateindex' 

Server: Msg 15633, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_fulltext_table, Line 364
Full-text auto propagation is currently enabled for table 'DiaryEntry'.

sp_fulltext_table @tabname='Ticket', @action='start_background_updateindex' 
Server: Msg 15633, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_fulltext_table, Line 364
Full-text auto propagation is currently enabled for table 'Ticket'.
```

Obviously a table *has* an indexing status, i just want to know it show i can display it to the user (i.e. me).

The other available API:

```
EXECUTE sp_help_fulltext_tables
```

only returns the tables that are in the catalog, it doesn't return their status.

```
TABLE_OWNER  TABLE_NAME  FULLTEXT_KEY_INDEX_NAME  FULLTEXT_KEY_COLID  FULLTEXT_INDEX_ACTIVE  FULLTEXT_CATALOG_NAME
===========  ==========  =======================  ==================  =====================   =====================
dbo          DiaryEntry  PK_DiaryEntry_GUID       1                   1                      FrontlineFTCatalog
dbo          Ticket      PK__TICKET_TicketGUID    1                   1                      FrontlineFTCatalog
```

And i can get the **PopulateStatus** of an entire catalog:

```
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('MyCatalog', 'PopulateStatus') AS PopulateStatus
```

which returns a status for the catalog:

```
0 = Idle 
1 = Full population in progress
2 = Paused 
3 = Throttled 
4 = Recovering 
5 = Shutdown 
6 = Incremental population in progress 
7 = Building index 
8 = Disk is full. Paused.
9 = Change tracking
```

but not for a table.

---

SQL Server 2000 SP4

```
SELECT @@version
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.194 (Intel X86) 
    Aug  6 2000 00:57:48 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2000 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.0 (Build 2195: Service Pack 4)
```

Regardless of any bug, i want to create UI to easily be able to see its status.

Comment: Have you tried the sql tips link ? THe script gets you 

All the Catalog names under the database
Table Name
If the Catalog is Enabled or Disabled
Change Tracking Option
Populate Status
Row Count
Full Text Search Count
Difference between total row count and Full Text Search Count
Percent Completed
Full Text Search Location/Path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christ. i had a whole nicely formatted answer. i was scrolling to hit save when IE crashed.

Short version:

**OBJECTPROPERTY**

- TableFullTextPopulateStatus
- TableFullTextBackgroundUpdateIndexOn
- TableFullTextCatalogId
- TableFullTextChangeTrackingOn
- TableFullTextKeyColumn
- TableHasActiveFulltextIndex

TableFullTextBackgroundUpdateIndexOn
    1=TRUE
    0=FALSE

TableFullTextPopulateStatus
    0=No population
    1=Full population
    2=Incremental population

Full example:

```
SELECT
    --indicates whether full-text change-tracking is enabled on the table (0, 1)
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('DiaryEntry'), 'TableFullTextChangeTrackingOn') AS TableFullTextChangeTrackingOn,

    --indicate the population status of a full-text table (0=No population, 1=Full Population, 2=Incremental Population)
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('DiaryEntry'), 'TableFullTextPopulateStatus') AS TableFullTextPopulateStatus,

    --indicates whether a table has full-text background update indexing (0, 1)
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('DiaryEntry'), 'TableFullTextBackgroundUpdateIndexOn') AS TableFullTextBackgroundUpdateIndexOn,

    -- provides the full-text catalog ID in which the full-text index data for the table resides (0=table is not indexed)
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('DiaryEntry'), 'TableFullTextCatalogId') AS TableFullTextCatalogId,

    --provides the column ID of the full-text unique key column (0=table is not indexed)
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('DiaryEntry'), 'TableFullTextKeyColumn') AS TableFullTextKeyColumn,

    --indicates whether a table has an active full-text index (0, 1)
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('DiaryEntry'), 'TableHasActiveFulltextIndex') AS TableHasActiveFulltextIndex
```

Comment: Might be me misunderstanding your issue; but this wont tell you that it isn't indexing the data; only how it _should_ be indexing the data.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL / Service pack are you running; this used to be a bug in sql 2000

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290212

execute the sp_fulltext_table in this sequence to temporarily fix the issue. (The low disk space is likely the cause)

- stop_change_tracking
- start_change_tracking
- stop_background_updateindex
- start_background_updateindex

OK to monitor the status you need to look at this very handy resource on [SQL Server FTI](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1681) on MSSQL Tips; i think the script there will give you what you are looking for.